# Mysql sorting issue

Tags: mysql

I have a table like following

```
ID    Position
1        A1
2        A2
3        A3
4        A4
5        A5
6        A6
7        A7
8        A8
9        A9
10       A10
11       A11
12       A12
13       B1
.
.
22       B10
.
.        H12
```

Note that the ID is not unique but positions are unique

when I do

```
Select * from <tablename>
```

I get

> A1, B1, C1, D1, E1... H1...H12

as output
and when I do

```
 Select * from <tablename> order by Position
```

I get

> A1, A10, A11, A12, A2, A3 .....

as output

I wanna sort it such that my output is A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A6,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,B1,B2... H12..

What should be the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> ORDER BY SUBSTR(position FROM 1 FOR 1), CAST(SUBSTR(position FROM 2) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: Thanks.. btw whats CAST(SUBSTR(position FROM 2) doing

Comment: it's converting/casting substring of your 'position' to unsigned

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort by a main category and a sub-category you will be better off using two INT columns.

Execute the query ONCE.

Loop through the results for each main category.

If you're using PHP use seek to reset the array..

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

if ($result1)
{
 // While loop most likely, iterate main categories.
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
 {
  //Stuff
 }

 // reset $result1
 // resets anything associated with result1 (e.g. $row1)
 mysql_data_seek($result1,0);

 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
 {
  //iterate for sub-categories
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a SQL query that I can use to sort it the way I want in MySQL?

Comment: You want to store data the correct way otherwise you're going to acrew a massive headache over time as you divert further away from the way data is intended to be handled.

Use ORDER BY <column_name> DESC or Use ORDER BY <column_name> ASC to sort, apply the sort to the MAIN category and then sort in the scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

this is bad. you think you are asking for a different sort, but you are really treating the position column as two values... the char and the number (each of which is sorted differently)

you might consider changing the data.  zero padding the positions would do it. A01 instead of A1

or you could have a pos_group = A, pos_number = 1

or you could try this ugly hack, which is probably not going to perform very well.

```
select * from <t1> order by left(position,1), substring(position from 2);
```

Comment: It gives the same output as select * from <t1> order by position